# Как найти код яндекс счётчика в шаблоне?

Tags: битрикс

Сейчас на сайте на главной странице два разных яндекс-счётчика, на остальных страницах один счётчик. Если в админке зайти в шаблон главной страницы, то там есть код только одного счётчика
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
код выглядит примерно так:

```
 <!-- Yandex.Metrika counter --><script type="text/javascript" data-skip-moving=true> (function (d, w, c) {(w[c] = w[c] || []).push(function () {try {w.yaCounter
```

Имеется несколько шаблонов для сайта
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В остальных шаблонах кроме главной вообще нет кода счётчика если зайти из админки в шаблон, хотя как говорил выше, на сайте счётчик есть на всех страницах, на главной их вообще два.
Подскажите, как найти этот код счётчика на всех страницах?
Нужно установить код счётчика, который сейчас на главной, установить его также на остальных страницах, а старый убрать.
Откуда ещё может подключаться код счётчика?

P.S. php_interface - init.php

```
<?
AddEventHandler("main", "OnEpilog", "_Check404Error",1);

function _Check404Error()
{
    global $APPLICATION;
    $cp = $APPLICATION->GetCurPage();
    if (defined("ERROR_404") && ERROR_404=="Y" && $cp!='/404.php')
    {
                $APPLICATION->RestartBuffer();
                //LocalRedirect("/404.php",false,404);
                //require ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/index.php");

        include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/bitrix/templates/vacancy/header.php';
        require ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/404.php");
        include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/bitrix/templates/main/footer.php';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: если на всех страницах один, а на главной - два, значит второй счетчик подключается непосредственно в коде главной страницы

Comment: @Grundy, так вопрос был в том, как найти код не на главной, а на остальных. То что он подключается на главной, я про это выше сказал

Comment: У тебя перепутались понятия _шаблон сайта_ и _шаблон страницы_

Comment: @Grundy, хорошо, как найти этот код главной страницы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раз у вас только на главной два счетчика, а на всех остальных один, проблема не в шаблоне, а в главной странице. Откройте через редактор главную страницу, обычно это `index.php` в корне проекта и поищите js код счетчика.

Comment: так проблема как раз в том, что на главной я нахожу счётчик, а на остальных нигде нет подключения этого счётчика, ни в index.php ни в header.php, ни в footer.php, ни в админке, в разделе "Шаблоны сайта". Нужно удалить счётчик не на главной, а на остальных страницах! Это ведь хорошо видно из скриншотов

Comment: всё нашёл, был в корне сайта, в файле sect_counters.php. Благодарю вас за подсказку

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67708/discussion-on-answer-by-maxkrasnov-------).